# Difference between ferrite pipe core and full ferrite core?

Tags: inductance, coil, ferrite

Disclaimer: I’m computer scientist

It is possible to buy ferrite pipe core coils and full ferrite core coils. The seller sell them for audio applications.

I’m considering using the coil to measure a slow varying magnetic field (<10kHz) of low induced voltage intensity (<1V).

How could this difference affect the induced voltage ? Is it relevant ?

**Edit 1**: There is no data sheet. Here is the documentation on the producer’s web page of a coil I bought for testing: https://www.mundorf.com/audio/en/shop/coils/pipe_coils/MCoil-P50-PipeCore/?card=3295.

Comment: Links to datasheets please.

Comment: The shape and construction of the core as well as how you wind the coil will have an effect on how well your coil picks up the external magnetic field.  The most extreme example is the comparison between a toroidal wound coil on a cylindrical ferrite core compared to a coil wound around the same core.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how you intend to tell the difference between the signal from your driving coil and the induced signal from your sample.  They'll be at the same frequency (as far as I can tell from your earlier questions) and will occur at the same time.

Comment: If there is no datasheet, don't use it.

Comment: @JRE The two coils are not used at the same time. I want to test if there is a remanent varying field.

Comment: The link is an inductor, possibly air core.

Comment: @Winny it is documented as a FERRITE / ARONIT PipeCore coil. See https://www.mundorf.com/audio/en/shop/Coils/Pipe_Coils/

Comment: Right. So it’s an inductor. Without a datasheet of said “full core”, I can only speculate that it would refer to a core where the magnetic field is all (effectively, in practice you always have some field lines escaping) enclosed in a magnetic material. Your “pin” design is not, so low Al but soft saturation behavior too. Take a look at a torpid and a drum core and compare.